# Add fragment at certain angle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have multiple fragments dynamically changing within my activity. Some instances fragments need to be added in landscape orientation while some in portrait. How do I specify the angle at which a fragment must be added to an activity ?

My current code:

```
getfragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(R.animator.fadein, R.animator.fadeout)
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, playerPane, tag).commit();
```

onCreateView Method:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_player_pane, container, false);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) rootView.getLayoutParams();

    // set width height
    params.height = (getArguments().getInt(HEIGHT));
    params.width = (getArguments().getInt(WIDTH));


    params.setMargins((getArguments().getInt(LEFT_MARGIN)),
            (getArguments().getInt(TOP_MARGIN)),
            (getArguments().getInt(RIGHT_MARGIN)),
            (getArguments().getInt(BOTTOM_MARGIN)));

    rootView.setLayoutParams(params);

    return rootView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the configuration of the device to see whether it is in portrait or landscape and use that in an if statement to launch a different fragment.

```
if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
    // launch portrait fragment
} else {
    // launch landscape fragment
}
```

As an addition, if I were writing this application, I would try not to change which fragment is being added depending on orientation, but rather have the fragment itself present its views differently depending on orientation through the use of targeted XML and checks within that fragment itself.

Answer (score 0):

Well fragment will have one Root View, You set the angle for it and have rotations.

```
1. Programatically

 view.setRotation((float) 45.0); //example

 2. Xml 
            android:rotation=""
            android:rotationX=""
            android:rotationY=""
```

> I was wondering whats the need of doing this. If its really required for supporting multiple orientation issues please go through below link
>
> [multiple screens support](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)